# Jenkins variables outside of job

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins job with many duplicate data inside. Sometimes I need to duplicate the job for crating new project. 
What I need is some tool to create variable outside Jenkins job and then use it in the project. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

1. use one of your existing jobs
2. take its XML configuration and use it to create an XML template file
3. then use [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) or [`xmlstarlet`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to replace specific placeholders/tags
4. then use the Jenkins CLI or REST API to create new jobs from the updated XML

Answer (score 1):

Can't environment variables do the job?

Anyway, I would use some text/DSL based tool like [Jenkins Job Builder](http://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/) (the first that came to my mind), so define your job as a template with generic variables, then create a Master Job that calls your job by passing such variables.